# check all jquery not working for dynamically populated checkbox

Tags: jquery, checkbox, attributes

I have a jquery function to select all checkboxes , which are populated in PHP loop. The output of the loop is similar to below:

```
<label class="check"><input type="checkbox" name="selectall" value="All"/> Select All</label>
<label class="col-md-3 col-xs-12 control-label">Types Of function</label>
<div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">                                                                                            
    <div class="col-md-7">                                    
        <label class="check"><input type="checkbox"  name="chkUser" class="icheckbox"/> Birthday</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-7">                                    
        <label class="check"><input type="checkbox"  name="chkUser" class="icheckbox"/> Family Function</label>                   
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-7">                                    
        <label class="check"><input type="checkbox"  name="chkUser" class="icheckbox"/> conference</label>                        
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-7">                                    
        <label class="check"><input type="checkbox"  name="chkUser" class="icheckbox"/> wedding</label>                           
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-7">                                    
        <label class="check"><input type="checkbox"  name="chkUser" class="icheckbox"/> Corporate</label>                             
    </div>
</div>
```

And the jquery function is :

```
$('.selectall').click(function() { //alert('HHH');
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        $('.icheckbox').attr('checked', 'checked');
    } else {
        $('.icheckbox').attr('checked', false);
    }
});
```

But unfortunately its not working ! What's wrong ?

Jsfiddle [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/fe8px5ty/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use **prop()** for setting checked and unchecked

```
  $('[name=selectall]').change(function() {  
         $('.icheckbox').prop('checked', this.checked);
    });
```

NOTE: there is no **selectall** class in your html

**[prop demo](https://jsfiddle.net/fe8px5ty/5/)**

**[attr domo](https://jsfiddle.net/fe8px5ty/7/)** working only once

Answer (score 1):

1. You have to add `class="selectall"` to ***selectall*** check box

```
<input type="checkbox" name="selectall" value="All" class="selectall">
```

2. It's recommend to use **prop()** as Bala suggested.

Answer (score 0):

$(document).ready(function ()
        {
            $('[name=selectall]').click(function () {

```
            if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
                $('.icheckbox').attr('checked', 'checked');
            } else {
                $('.icheckbox').attr('checked', false);
            }
        });
    });
```

or 
Change label name to Id and try  below code

$(document).ready(function () 
         {
            $('#selectall').click(function () {

```
            if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
                $('.icheckbox').attr('checked', 'checked');
            } else {
                $('.icheckbox').attr('checked', false);
            }
        });
    });
```